# By using Android Sqlite Database (or a local database ) ,will other people be able to use my app on Google store?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on a notepad app. I am  wondering if other people be able to use my app on Google store, if I use SQ LITE as database?

Comment: Since android actually uses sqlite....well yes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use the [official approach](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) to it (using the internal database tools of Android), it should work for everyone, since the database is created on each device.

If, however, you are working with a seperate database file, which is not contained within the application source, they couldn't access it, since they wouldn't have a copy of it.